# Dynamic field insertion when creating python dictionary

Tags: python

I would like to dynamicly add/ don't add a field when creating a python dictionary.

```
def my_func(input):
    return {
         'foo':'bar',
         None if input == None else 'baz':input
        }
```

This actually works but it returns `{'foo': 'bar', None: None}`

I would like it to return `{'foo': 'bar'}`. Is there a way to do that?

PS. I know this question is a bit academic. One could easily do:

```
def my_func(input):
    ret = {
         'foo':'bar',
            }
    if input != None:
        ret['baz'] = input
    return ret
```

but I like the first one for cleanness.

[EDIT]

Could we use an `__metaclass__` to solve this?

Comment: I don't see the advantage of not putting the 'baz' key into your dict when the input is None. That way you have to check whether the _key is present_ in any subsequent code. This check would otherwise be a check if the _value is None_. Either way you have to check sth before proceeding ...

Comment: Normally yes, but I feed this dictionary to an external library. That blows on {'foo': 'bar', None: None} and on {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': None}.

Answer (score 0):

You be wanting [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

`collections.default` works like a normal dict with one exception, you can set a default_factory, when you do a['test'] and the key is `__missing__` then it will call default factory. In default factory you can make it do anything you want to give it a default value.

Comment: That could solve the problem of consuming this dict. However this way I can't use the default dict constructor, so it defies the purpose a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with [jellybean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178560/jellybean).
but if you really need it, and really need it as oneliner, then you can do something like:

```
def my_func(input):
   return dict([(k,v) for k,v in (('foo', 'bar'), ('buz', inp)) if v])
```

Of course it doesn't cover case when some other values are also None... (And it's ugly. I really don't know why i've posted this :) )

And, imho, second variant you posted is absolutely ok in your case.

```
def my_func(input):
    ret = {'foo':'bar'}
    if input:
        ret['baz'] = input
    return ret
```

Comment: Ok, that is ugly indeed ;) Don't worry I won't use it, although it is an interesting solution